# Lower bound related to the number of distinct prime numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization, arithmetic-functions

Let $\omega(n)$ be the number of distinct prime factors of $n$ (without multiplicity, of course). I know some results about average of $\omega(n)$. But I didn't find any result about the following: Let $k\geq 2$ be an integer, then there exists some good lower bound for
$$
\# \{n\leq x : \omega(n)\geq k\}?
$$

Good means we can ensure that the set $\{n\geq 1 : \omega(n)\geq k\}$ has positive upper density, i.e.,
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\sup\displaystyle\frac{
\# \{n\leq x : \omega(n)\geq k\}
}{x}
$$
is positive? If so, some lower bound?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, for any fixed $k$, the set $\{n\colon \omega(n)\ge k\}$ has density $1$. This follows from the [Hardy–Ramanujan theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Ramanujan_theorem), which is the even stronger statement that for any fixed $\varepsilon>0$, the set
$$
\{ n\colon |\omega(n) - \log\log n| < (\log\log n)^{1/2+\varepsilon} \}
$$
has density $1$.

A related result, often called the Selberg–Sathe theorem, actually gives the asymptotic formula
$$
\#\{n\le x\colon \omega(n)=k\} \sim \frac x{\log x}\frac{(\log\log x)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}.
$$
In particular, this set has density $0$ for every fixed $k$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Dear @Greg Martin, where can I find the asymptotic formula
$$
\#\{n\le x\colon \omega(n)=k\} \sim \frac x{\log x}\frac{(\log\log x)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}?
$$
I found here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.01963.pdf, but with some factor $G((k-1)/\log \log x)$, where $G$ is a function depending on an infinite product and the Gamma function. Thanks

Comment: That version is also correct, indeed even better! That version works even if $k$ is growing with $x$. If $k$ is fixed, then the argument of $G$ tends to $0$ and the factor $G(0)=1$ disappears, leaving us with the version I put in this answer.—Two books one can find this theorem (indeed the uniform version you linked to, which implies the version in the answer) are Tenenbaum's _Introduction to Probabilistic and Analytic Number Theory_ and Montgomery & Vaughan's _Multiplicative Number Theory I_.

Comment: I would like to know if this function $G(z)=\Gamma(1+z)^{-1}\prod_{p} (1+z/p)(1-1/p)^z$ is well defined for all $z\in (0,2)$. Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, one can show that the infinite product converges uniformly and absolutely for $z$ in any bounded set.

Answer (score 2):

It follows from the [Erdős–Kac theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem) that this natural density is $1$ for all $k$. Informally speaking, the distribution of $\omega(n)$ approaches a normal distribution with mean and variance $\log\log n$, so the proportion of values below any fixed finite bound goes to zero.